# Can reborn Azor Ahai and the Prince that was promised be different persons?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

Some people assert that the prophecies about *reborn Azor Ahai* and *The Prince That Was Promised* are talking about the same person, but [Websites](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Azor_Ahai#Azor_Ahai_come_again) which state that it could be the same person, don't list much references.

The [prophecy about The Prince That Was Promised is very specific](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/The_prince_that_was_promised#Signs_of_the_coming_of_the_prince_that_was_promised), while the other one isn't:

> There will come a day after a long summer when the stars bleed and the cold breath of darkness falls heavy on the world. In this dread hour a warrior shall draw from the fire a burning sword. And that sword shall be Lightbringer, the Red Sword of Heroes, and he who clasps it shall be Azor Ahai come again, and the darkness shall flee before him.

In season 6's seventh and eighth episodes it looks like another person is directed to becoming Azor Ahai's revenant.

> The Hound is affected by fire since his childhood, he survived a trial by battle against reviving Beric Dondarrion, he is still living because a priest healed him and now it's very likely that he joins R'hllor's forces besides the Red Priest.

So is it possible that reborn Azor Ahai and The Prince That Was Promised are two different persons? Or what is the evidence that it's the same person?

Clarification: I'm only asking about the prophecies, not about who the person(s) will be.

Comment: It's an issue of convention. It seems that up until now, The George wants us to believe that they're different characters; however, he's left enough hints for us to figure out that they're actually the same. Most people have taken this belief as literal and say it as canon, when it in fact hasn't been confirmed. The George himself may have said they're the same by accident, however it's not to be considered canon just yet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes both prophecies refer to the same figure with different names. Following is the evidence:

### Role of different cultures and their languages

Azor Ahai and Prince that was promised apparently refer to same prophetic figure. They are just different names used by different cultures to refer to one supposed figure who would lead the men into Battle for the Dawn. People of Asshai call him Azor Ahai and People of Westeros call him Prince that was promised.

According to the World of Ice and Fire, In some other culture, legends point to the same figure with different names such as Hyrkoon the Hero, Yin Tar, Neferion, and Eldric Shadowchaser.

### Melisandre's conversation with Maester Aemon

There is not much information available about TPTWP as compared to AA. By the description she gave for Azor Ahai's duty, Maester Aemon quickly knew that she was talking about TPTWP and Battle for the Dawn.

From ASOS, Chapter 78, Sam's POV:

> “Swords alone cannot hold this darkness back. Only the light of the
>   Lord can do that. Make no mistake, good sers and valiant brothers, the
>   war we’ve come to fight is no petty squabble over lands and honors.
>   Ours is a war for life itself, and should we fail the world dies with
>   us.”
>
> The officers did not know how to take that, Sam could see. Bowen Marsh
>   and Othell Yarwyck exchanged a doubtful look, Janos Slynt was fuming,
>   and Three-Finger Hobb looked as though he would sooner be back
>   chopping carrots.
>
> But all of them seemed surprised to hear Maester Aemon murmur, “**It
>   is the war for the dawn you speak of, my lady. But where is the prince
>   that was promised?**”
>
> “**He stands before you**,” Melisandre declared, “though you do not have
>   the eyes to see. **Stannis Baratheon is Azor Ahai come again, the
>   warrior of fire. In him the prophecies are fulfilled. The red comet
>   blazed across the sky to herald his coming, and he bears Lightbringer,
>   the red sword of heroes.**”

Notice that Aemon asked who was TPTWP. Mel replied that Stannis was Azor Ahai. Which means they must be the same person. Later Maester Aemon does not say that if they are different figures or not, he just asks to see Stannis's magical sword Light Bringer. He saw it and left. Afterwards when he was dying, He told Sam this, In AFFC Chapter 35:

> The sword is wrong, she has to know that ... light without heat ... an
>   empty glamour ... the sword is wrong, and the false light can only
>   lead us deeper into darkness.

He did not say that Melisandre was wrong to consider AA and TPTWP to be same persons, He just says that she has the sword wrong. Which means that TPTWP must also posses the same sword and characteristics.

### The Sword

By what we know of TPTWP, We know that he must be a Warrior, so he must need a sword. Back when Rhaegar used to think he was TPTWP, he said this to Master-at-arms of KL:

> I will require a sword and armor. It seems I must be a warrior.

And we know AA forged his own magical sword to slay the darkness (By plunging the sword into heart of his beloved wife to temper it).

### So Spake Martin

In GoT Season-2 DVD Extras GRRM also used the word in a similar way. He said:

> He [Stannis] is discarding the gods that he has worshiped since his
>   childhood and accepting the red god and giving himself to the lord of
>   light. And in return, **Melisandre sees that the lord of light gives
>   him a token of his role as the prince that was promised by an ancient
>   prophecy**. And of course, that's his sword Lightbringer.

Notice that Mel usually refers to Stannis as Azor Ahai, but George states that Mel sees him as TPTWP. That should clear it all up.

You can view the talk [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DIe0Q3PgcOw&t=415).

Comment: The quote of Martin is great. Even if in-universe there could be a confusion about both prophecies, mixing Azor Ahai's sword Lightbringer with The Prince That Was Promised isn't a mistake GRRM is likely to make.

Answer (score 1):

On the WoIaF page for [The Prince that was Promised](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/The_prince_that_was_promised) they use that title and Azor Ahai interchangeably. It even says that:

> Melisandre has mentioned the prince that was promised and Azor Ahai interchangeably but she tends to use the name Azor Ahai far more often.

This exact line is also found on the page for [Azor Ahai](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Azor_Ahai). Though the next line in the same paragraph says that:

> Aemon only mentions the prince that was promised, never the name Azor Ahai.

The page goes on to say that:

> Azor Ahai and the prince that was promised may be two distinct prophecies, or they may be one in the same in a prophecy that has the potential to turn out to be about two separate people.

**TL;DR**

We don't know yet. I think that we won't know until the prophecy comes true one way or the other.

Comment: Hi, that quotes are from the pages I've linked. At least  I hoped for a quote of the chapter where Melisandre uses both names. And for clarification I only ask about the prophecies, so we don't need to wait for the prophecy to be fulfilled. If both prophecies will be fulfilled by the same person doesn't matter.

Comment: I unfortunately don't have access to my books right now, but I'll add the quote if I'm able to find it.

Comment: -1 There are quotes in the book in which Azor Ahai and TPTWP are used as same person e.g. Mel's conversation with Maester Aemon. So your assumption that there is no quote in this regard is wrong. I will be happy to remove it if you were to add appropriate evidence and remove the said wrong assumption

Comment: @Aegon Your answer is much better than mine in the completeness category, but I don't think that my answer is wrong. We could probably argue semantics all day long, but I think that your answer hinges on the view of one person, Mel. Someone that has been wrong about Azor Ahai before. I will however, remove the part about no quote, you're 100% right about that!

Comment: @Telestia I never said your answer was wrong or bad. It is a perfectly good answer. I told you why I DV'd. Now that you have removed the wrong bit, I have removed the downvote as well. I left the comment only to let you know why the DV, instead of an anonymous DV which does not result in improvement of content. Cheers!